# The straight lines are contained in $S$

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I am looking at the following exercise:

The hyperboloid of one sheet is
$$S=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2+y^2-z^2=1\}$$ 
Show that, for every $\theta$, the straight line
$$(x − z) \cos \theta = (1 − y) \sin \theta, \ \ (x + z) \sin \theta = (1 + y) \cos \theta \tag 1$$ 
is contained in $S$, and that every point of the hyperboloid lies on one of these lines.

Deduce that $S$ can be covered by a single surface patch, and hence is a surface.

$$$$

I have done the following:

Multiplying the two equations of $(1)$ we get $$(x^2+y^2-z^2-1)\cos \theta \sin \theta=0 \\ \Rightarrow x^2+y^2-z^2=1 \text{ unless } \cos \theta =0 \text{ or } \sin \theta =0$$

If $\cos \theta=0$ then $y=1, x=-z$ $\rightarrow (-z,1,z)\in S$.

If $\sin \theta=0$ then $x=z, y=-1$ $\rightarrow (z,-1,z)\in S$.

So, for each $\theta$, the line $(1)$ is  contained in $S$.

Is this correct?

$$$$

Then we take a point of the hyperboloid, $(x,y,z)$.

How can we show that this lies on the one of these lines?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

How could we deduce that $S$ can be covered by a single surface patch, and hence is a surface?

Also how could we find a second family of straight lines on $S$, and show that no two lines of the same family intersect, while every line of the first family
intersects every line of the second family with one exception?

Answer (score 3):

Take a point on $S$, $p = (x,y,z)$. We know that

$x^2 + y^2 - z^2 - 1 = 0$.

Thus $(x+z)(x-z) = (1+y)(1-y)$. Suppose $(x-z) \not = 0$ and $(1+y) \not = 0$ (you can do these two cases by hands). Then of course

$\frac{x+z}{1+y} =  \frac{1-y}{x-z} = a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Since $ctg(x)$ is onto, there is $\theta$ such that $a = ctg(\theta) = \frac{cos(\theta)}{sin(\theta)}$, so you get

$(x+z)sin(\theta) = (1+y)cos(\theta)$

and

$(x-z)cos(\theta) = (1-y)sin(\theta)$.

Comment: I forgot to say that what you have done is actually correct!

Comment: We have to suppose that $x-z\neq$ and $1+y\neq 0$, right? What can we do at the cases where $x-z=0$ or $1+y=0$ ?

Comment: The case $x-z = 0$ and $1+y =0$ is easy. These two equations define a line, that you can rewrite making multiplication with $sin(0)$ and $cos(0)$ as $(x-z)cos(0) = (1-y)sen(0)$ and $(x+z)sin(0) = (1+y)cos(0)$. When just one of them is verified, one equation is trivially true $0=0$, you can just solve the other in order to find $\theta$. For example when $x-z=0$ and $y-1=0$ then just take $\theta = arcctg(x)$ you get $x = cos/sin$ thus $2xsin(\theta) = 2cos(\theta)$ and so using the two equations you get $(x+z)sin(\theta) = (1+y)cos(\theta)$.

Comment: I got it!! Thank you for your answer!! :-) $$$$ I added two more questions in my inital post... Could you take a look at it? Do you have an idea?

Comment: This is your surface https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid

Comment: The Jacobian of $F(x,y,z):=x^2 + y^2 - z^2 - 1$ is $(0,0)$ only in $(0,0)$ so it is a smooth surface. You can move the lines continuously to go from a point $p$ to any point $q$ so it is  a single surface patch (ie connected)

Comment: Probably good lines are the one you get dividing for the other factors, ie $\frac{x+z}{1-y} =  \frac{1+y}{x-z} = a$ but I'm not sure about that and I'm not an expert! Check if they work!

Comment: Why can we move the lines continuously to go from a point $p$ to any point $q$ ? To conclude to that do we use the fact that the line is contained in $S$ for each $\theta$ and that each point of $S$ lies on the line for a specific $\theta$ ?

Comment: Exactly, you can change $\theta$ from $\theta_1$ to $\theta_2$ continuously remaining in $S$!

Comment: It's like you start on $p$, then you move thanks to $\theta$ in a circular path and arrive on a line containing $q$, then you move on that line to reach $q$.

Comment: The single surface patch that covers the surface is the line $(1)$, right? Which is a parametrization of this surface patch?

Comment: I didn't know you were looking for 1 chart! I don't know differential geometry to be honest, I just liked your question. By the way as far as I understood, you can't use a single chart in something like this that is similar to a cylinder, unless you allow charts from a generic open set, not only from simply connected one. If you allow punctured unit disk to be a chart you can use just 1 chart. It's like you stretch the punctured disk in the vertical direction while you enlarge the missing point. Try read here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243257/looking-for-an-atlas-with-1-chart?rq=1